# PHP "Foreach" issue

Tags: php

For the love of me, I'm not sure what is going on. I have few customers subscribing to an item that in out of stock. Now the item is in stock and I got this:

```
Undefined variable: items in (web url) Warning: Invalid argument supplies for foreach()
```

When I found the line, its this code here:

But somewhere along:

```
<?php foreach($items as $item){ ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $item['href']; ?>"><?php echo $item['name']; ?></a> - (<?php echo $item['count']; ?>)</li> 
<?php } ?>
```

has the issue. Everything seems correct, to me. Is it?

Comment: Can a mod format my question please? I don't know how to.

Comment: Looks like $items array is null. Where is it set?

Comment: $items is not an array? The error is pretty clear

Comment: post the code where the `$items` var is set/defined/declared/whatever.

Comment: @iMayne try to  explain $items with print_r($items);

Comment: `$items` is not defined, end of story. There is nothing in your code that suggests they would be.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this (if all you want to do is remove the warning):

```
<?php if (isset($items) && is_array($items)) { foreach($items as $item){ ?>
```

and

```
<?php }} ?>
```

Alternatively, look into the PHP 'error_reporting' and 'display_errors' directives which can be used to hide the warning.

Comment: Looks like $items is not even set; that being the case, this code would also give errors ($items not defined)

Comment: This is much like saying "try not using $items at all". It's impossible to debug this problem with only the code in the post. Re: Your edit - "Hiding" errors/warnings is not what you should do while developing, and it is not equivalent to fixing them. Hiding errors messages is a great way to totally miss bugs in your code, and you should actually suggest a *higher* level of error reporting to debug the issue.

Comment: Wow, quick to dole out the negatives, still editing! Also, warning is just that, a warning. This guy has 'customers' so is obviously in production.

Comment: @Ryan That's another good reason for not hiding the errors but figuring out how to solve them. Customers woulnd't be happier if the site didn't show any error, but their cart is still empty! At least the error would give them a sense of what's going on (for what that matters)

Comment: I am not suggesting he turn in off unless all he is trying to do is remove the message, but you are probably right, better to know than not to know

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Im not a master in php but Im getting there. Your code worked perfectly!

I got my coding help from a php website with this code:

<?php

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->nodeValue . "\n";
}

?>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right in front of you. In the error, it says `undefined variable: items...`

Make sure that `$items` is defined before you use it, with something like `if( isset($items) )`